# Does the total tag number earn a badge?

Tags: discussion, feature-request

There is a number beside tag in profile which seems to be the total sum of all the tag points for each tag.  Is there a a badge for it?  For instance, if I answer a question in every single tag, my points would be say 1 or 2 for each one, giving me no chance of getting a tag badge anytime soon (as I need 100).  But I could have 1000 total tag points, because I might be a jack-of-all-trades, master-of-none.   Something like a "Generalist" badge.  Does it exist, or have been considered?

Comment: The only thing that comes *close* is the [Generalist](http://stackoverflow.com/help/badges/15/generalist), which requires the *top* badges for the site, and isn't dependent on the total number of badges that you've interacted with.

Comment: Oh I didn't even know it existed.  However, wouldn't the top 20 tags change over time?

Answer (score 3):

Badges are meant to encourage positive interactions with the site.  Badges like "Good Answer" or "Curious" are meant to award a user for answering a question well, or for asking a question well respectively.

The total number of tags that you've interacted with is a happy coincidence, and is easily subject to change, since a question may be edited and lose or gain tags.  It wouldn't make sense to introduce a badge just because you've participated in *n* tags, since that's just a thing that happens.

As I said before, the only thing that comes close is the [Generalist](https://stackoverflow.com/help/badges/15/generalist) badge, which only takes into account the top 40 badges for a particular site.